# Link My Documents folder to external SD Card

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, sd-card

I have a laptop with 120GB SSD (limited space) and a 64GB SD card in the laptop. I have cloned my hard drive from a clean install of all the software installed.

I would like to have the My Documents folder linked to the SD card which is E:/ drive, so that when I reinstall back from the clean operating system, I can have all the info in My Documents there.

What are my options of doing this? I do not want to change the location of My Documents, just have a copy of it or a matching copy of this on the SD Card. I have looked at symbolic links or maybe a hard link, but I am unsure which would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two options, redirect Documents folder in registry or create symbolic link. I recommend using registry option, it's easier and you don't need any extra utils.

**Redirecting method**

1. Open `regedit.exe` (via Run <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Find key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
3. Change path under REG_SZ record called `Personal` to your SD
4. Logoff and back on

On pro version of Windows, you may do this also via `gpedit.msc`.

**Symbolic link**

Download utility `junction` from Microsoft Systeminternals. Delete your Documents folder and run from command line:

```
junction c:\users\%username%\Documents X:
```

(replace `X:` with path on your sdcard)

Comment: Junctions are the way to go. I have my entire users folder structure on a separate drive, with the OS and apps on an SSD. Used a junction to map Users transparently so the system thinks it's on C where Windows expects it to be.

Comment: But that's also a bit fragile, because system won't boot without Users dirs. I would create admin user and then change `ProfilesDirectory` registry value. That way you have a possibility to fallback and all newly created user profiles are created at SSD location.

Comment: [Do not rely on those registry keys.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx)

Comment: Well, I know that those were the days, but "The Justice system works swiftly now that they've abolished all lawyers."...

Comment: System boots fine, because the junction is a hard link. As far as the OS is concerned, Users is on C, but C:\Users is actually physically located on D:\Users. If you don't want to muck with this, try this tip instead: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18629-user-folders-change-default-location.html

Answer (score 0):

In the past, When playing Minecraft, I used to use windows task scheduler and a batch file to copy the contents of my game folder to a 'backup location', using wscript, which is probably present on your system in the system32 folder.

Open task manager and create a new task with the interval you want under triggers.

Under the actions tab, create a new 'start a program' action.

#### The program/script:

> C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe

#### Arguments:

"X:\directory\invisible.vbs" "X:\directory\operation.bat"

Create the two files in the desired directory.

#### The invisible.vbs contains:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

#### the operation.bat contains something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
xcopy /E /I "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\*" "F:\my documents-%RANDOM%-%Random%\"
```

What this operation does is create a my documents folder with random values. This allows me to keep more then one backup. In your case, you'd probably not want to do that, but just overwrite what was already there (keeping one folder).

```
@ECHO OFF
xcopy /E /I "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\*" "F:\Documents\"
```

The **E** argument copies all sub-directories, even if empty, and the **I** argument, indicates you are copying a directory. You'd probably want to add **Y**, which would not prompt you if file already exists.

[More info on arguments](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128756)

There is of course more elegant solutions. Just thought I'd share something that has worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Junction point

1. Log off and log on with an administrator account.
2. Rename the `C:\Users\<username>\Documents` folder to something else (e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\Documents.old`).
3. Create a `Users\<username>\Documents` folder in drive `E:`, then copy all files/folders from `C:\Users\<username>\Documents.old`.
4. Create a junction point by running the following command in a command prompt:

   ```
   mklink /j "C:\Users\<username>\Documents" "E:\Users\<username>\Documents"
   ```

   The syntax is:

   ```
   mklink /j "<junction point>" "<target folder>"
   ```

   Quotes are required to avoid issues with space characters.

### Known limitations

- You won't have access to the targeted folder in case the drive letter changes.
- [Junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) and symbolic links are only supported on NTFS.
- You can't create junction points targeting remote shares. In such cases you have to create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) instead. Symbolic links were introduced with Windows Vista, but are also available in Windows XP through third party filter drivers. For Vista and later, the syntax is the following:

  ```
  mklink /d "symbolic link" "X:\path\to\target\folder"
  ```

  **Note** Per default system settings, only users in the Administrators group can create symbolic links.