# How to get Windows Photo Gallery to store its thumbnails in a non-default place?

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-8.1, windows-photo-gallery

It looks like Windows Photo Gallery stores thumbnails for photos in this location: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Photo Gallery`.

Is it possible to force it to store it on another drive?  My C drive (the SSD) is running out of space and it would be great if I could save some space.

Comment: use http://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php to move and link to folder back to the original location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing programs to be installed to another drive](http://superuser.com/questions/755465/forcing-programs-to-be-installed-to-another-drive), [Link My Documents folder to external SD Card](http://superuser.com/a/722292/289138)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link My Documents folder to external SD Card](http://superuser.com/questions/722084/link-my-documents-folder-to-external-sd-card)